# How should a browser extension "capture" all GET and POSTs to a specific URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, safari-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I want my extension to capture, and inject custom behavior for any GET or POST to a specific URL.

Access to these URLs can be done via

- A mouse click
- Javascript not written by me
- Perhaps another extension/plugin

I will know, however, the FORM POST/GET parameter names (not values).  When this occurs I'll create a security dialog of some kind.

**Question**

- How can I capture GET/POST events in a browser extension?

---

Documentation for plugins it difficult to find on some browsers , and I need to run compiled Mono/.NET code on OS X and PC, so if I abandon the plugin approach I may leverage [Safari Extension Companions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/CommunicatingwithyourOSXApplication/CommunicatingwithyourOSXApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH23-SW4), [Chrome Native Messaging API](https://blog.chromium.org/2013/10/connecting-chrome-apps-and-extensions.html), or the equivalent in Firefox

Due to compatibility issues with most sites, I don't want to create a dependency on a specific version of JQuery, in case that might somehow mess up the source website.

Comment: Browser plugins are written in native code e.g. Flash is a plugin. As for extensions see webRequest API.

Comment: You should the browser's `webRequest` extension API to take action directly in response to browser issuing HTTP requests: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis#webrequest,

Comment: Are you asking about plugins (native code), or extensions (JavaScript, generally))? The two are very different and have different answers. IMO, if you want to know about both, then it should be two separate questions as the techniques will be significantly different. Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: @Makyen It appears that the only documentation for Safari development is Extensions , not plugins.